# Running SQL query from a column in a table which may yield 2 more columns

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table which has 2 columns, One column contains the IDs and other contains SQL Queries which get counts, max functions(or any other queries) etc from other tables which which may yield 2 more columns. I need to get the id's and resultant columns from those Queries.I need to view these results using an asp.net Entity framework. Any suggestions of how we can go about this?

Comment: If I understand your question you want to execute the query and return that as part of the result along with the ID of that row?

Comment: Yes. That's what i intend to do. The ID can be displayed multiple times depending upon the size of the returned query

Comment: Do these queries have a concrete type or are they all adhoc queries?  Seems to me that you don't want to be using EF if they are adhoc and maybe you just want ADO.NET.

Comment: They are ad-hoc queries.That column will contain any kind of query which can do arithmetic  statements or functions like max, count etc

I have other tables in the entity framework too that are bringing in the the data from the database using entity framework.This will be an added table to the existing model.